# Keep the button Active after reloading the page

Tags: php, html, css, button, bootstrap-4

Is there any way where I can keep the button active after reloading the page? (Not using any custom CSS, only Bootstrap)

HTML

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 40px;"><p> Show All Conferences </p>
                
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="tab-content">
        <button style="margin-left: 35px;" type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button"> On </button>
        <button style="margin-left: -8px;" type="submit" name="submitBtn2" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="button"> Off </button>
    </form></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: There's likely something else in your code that's disabling the buttons. The code you posted here seems fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I take a quick scan of your code, and I see two submit buttons, but I don't see anything that would make a button *not* be active. Each time you reload the page, it should look exactly the way it did the last time it loaded.

Comment: PHP. I am using the buttons as a switch to ON or OFF, in an if condition. 
    function switch_on_off (){
 $dateConf = date('Ymd');
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) { //If ON is pressed          
        $dateConf = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2017-02-02 17:02:03'));
}if(isset($_POST['submitBtn2'])){ //If OFF is pressed
  $dateConf = date('Ymd');
}
   return $dateConf;
}

Comment: the problem is whenever the page reloads, because of the submit (button) the button selected does not stay active.

Comment: @Kim I am not sure what "active" means in this context, I think you should add that to your question, but in general, adding an active state (as defined by Bootstrap-4) can be done by programmatically adding the the `.active` class to the button - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#active-state

Comment: If i understand you currently, it seems you want state of the buttons to remain reflected after page reloads (and possibly permanently unless manually changed; i suspect?). If so then the "how" depends entirely on your PHP code. You'd have to show what happens with the $dateConf you mentioned above, does it get stored in a database or in the session variable for example ? also include the part of your PHP code which outputs the above html, as that'd likely have to include a `disabled` attribute on the currently active button.

Comment: I just the button to be a different color/state whenever the user clicks on it, since I have 2 buttons (ON/OFF), whenever the user clicks on one of them it should stay in a different color (to show that is ON or OFF).

Comment: @kim `don't` write code in comment like that, add them to your question